# bootstrap 3: input-group not work in chrome

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I work with Bootstrap 3. i have `input-group` and `input-group-addon` class for design my input box with this Code:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <label class="control-label">thumbnails</label>
    </td>
    <td colspan="3" class="">
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
            <a class="icon-picture boxGetFiles" id="btnChoiceThumbnail" href="#"></a>
            </span>
            <input type="text" name="thumbnail" class="form-control" id="thumbnail" tabindex="7" value=""/>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

This Code Work in FF true and show in full width :

[image]

But In Chrome This **not work** and **not show** in full width:(Version 39.0.2171.65 m)

[image]

how co can i fix this problem ?!

DEMO [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/1q9s3vtf/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `colspan="3"` or add `width: 100%` to the `.input-group`

[See updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1q9s3vtf/2/)